# Keyboard fingering, or what fingers should I use to type M-b and M-f in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, ergonomics

I have grown used to using my thumb on `Alt` and crossing over with my index finger to hit the `f` or the `b` key for moving forwards or backwords one word in Emacs. But now that I have a Daskeyboard Ultimate without lettering on the keys I find myself often missing. I guess I relied too much on looking at the keyboard. Anyway, I was wondering if there was a proper way to describe keyboard fingering similar to the way it is suggested in written piano scores. For this specific case, should the pinky be used? Using the pinky on `Alt` would make it difficult to hit other keys in the pinky column such as `q`, `a`, and `z`.

Comment: The proper keyboard technique was invented *before* the invention of computers, so there is no proper method for hitting keys that are not on a manual typewriter.  Moreover, the size and location of the modifier keys vary depending upon the keyboard.  I learned to type on a manual typewriter with carbon paper for making more than one copy -- those were the days of the real `cc` (carbon copy).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark that would defeat the purpose. I want to learn touch-typing by not allowing myself to look at the keys.

Comment: There isn't one true way of doing it. Xah Lee writes a lot on how to make Emacs more useful (in his view), here's example that deals with some typing problems: http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_pinky.html But I wouldn't use the keyboard he likes, neither some of his techniques appeal to me. I think that pressing meta with thumb is the way to go, feels comfortable on the keyboard I'm using. I also knew someone who swapped meta and control keys, while having control in place of capslock. He would press meta with the bottom-left side of his palm. I can't do it, but it was perfect for him.

Comment: The letters `f` and `j` each have a nodule (on most keyboards).  This is a throw-back to the stone-age when manual typewriters were once used -- it is to help a touch-typist quickly locate the home row using the index fingers (without needing to look).  You could put a drop of silicone on a modifier key to help you find the modifier key in the same manner, or remap the modifier key to an easier location to suit your needs, or you could cheat (e.g., by taking a peek).  I type 100 words per minute and still take a peek every now and again at the keys that were introduced with the computer age.

Comment: Using the thumb means you don't leave touch-typing position.
Although it's awkward to bend it when `Alt` is between `z` and `x`.
I'd be happy to get a keyboard with `Alt` under `c`.

Comment: Oh wait, are you pressing meta *under* the `z` when you need to press `M-x` No way... I meant the meta on the other side of the space! :) I.e. my `M-x` is with right thumb on the left meta and the ring finger of my left hand is on `x`.

Comment: @wvxvw, I don't press `M-x` at all. I've bound `smex` to `C-t` a long time ago.
But I'm still using `C-M-x` though: single hand pinkie+thumb+index:)

Comment: I also have to clarify: it's my right thumb on the *right* meta. I just tried to reproduce what I wrote before, and it looks like some kind of sorcery :D

Comment: You are right about not looking at the keys, to learn touch typing. just look at the screen. Obviously that can be more complicated for keys that act in complex ways (and perhaps do not show much in the way of visible changes).

Comment: @wvxvw is right, I should be using the right meta when I need to hit a combo with a left-hand key.

Answer (score 2):

You should use two hands whenever possible to minimise cross fingering. For this particular case:

- `M-b`, left hand for `Alt` and right hand for `b`
- `M-f`, right hand for `Alt` and left hand for `f`

I use the thumb to press `Alt` and the index for `b` and `f`.

Comment: Wow, this is so obvious but I missed it due to a many-years bad habit of only using the left-hand conrol, shift, and meta keys. I almost forgot that those keys are mirrored on the right hand. Now I'm wondering how to break bad keyboard habits...

Comment: I just got Microsoft's ergonomic keyboard from a friend and I shall say that b's placement is on the left half, so I now have to do M-b using my left hand. I might try to use right Alt, but it feels odd.